# How to short circuit with using push button

Tags: short-circuit

I am testing the ability to charge and recharge battery circuit. I have been testing using a push button in order to short circuit the battery and drain the charge.  I would like to instead use an arduino to replace the push button.  I tried using a 2n222 and an irf150 mosfet but neither of these shorted the battery.  I basically want the current to follow directly from the drain to the source when the pin is active.  I cannot get this to work.  Do anyone have an idea of a design?

Comment: Please show us the schematics for the circuits you tried with the 2n2222 and irf150. What do you mean when you say that they didn't "short" the battery? Usually, a direct short of a battery is a very dangerous thing...are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: Short-circuiting a battery is very bad practice and depending on the type can cause fire. For your testing you should be doing a controlled discharge to limit the current to a safe value as indicated in the datasheet for the battery. You should also shut of the discharge when a certain minimum voltage is reached. There is a CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar. Use that to add a schematic of the circuit you have created.

Comment: Why not connect some resistance in series instead of shorting? That can be very dangerous...

Comment: If you short the battery the transistor or mosfet will be damaged.  Use a series resistor to limit the current.  Look at the maximum current rating in the data sheet of the device.

Answer (score 1):

A proper discharge circuit for a battery will always have a loading device to discharge it safely. Usually, a device that pulls at the most, 80% of the discharge capacity. Using an arduino? well, I would set one up to discharge, and read my voltages at the same time, then light an led after the volt meter reads 0V.

So I would do something along the lines of:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I am simply compiling all the comments to the question since all of them are correct.

Never short the terminals of a battery. You are basically trying to short a voltage source which ideally causes infinite current to flow through the wire and actually causes a very large amount of current to flow (because of the very small series resistance of the battery). Instead, connect a series resistance in between.

You may use a Zener diode as well if you want to keep a cutoff below which you do not want the voltage of the battery to drop.

Comment: The second paragraph is not useful in practice.

Comment: @skvery please explain

Comment: If you connect a zener diode directly across the terminals of the battery, and the zener voltage is less than the battery voltage, then it will blow the diode.  You need something to limit the current.

Comment: Agree with @skvery - simply putting a zener across a battery will more-or-less instantly discharge the battery to the zener voltage. Depending on battery construction and chemistry, the zener may be destroyed or the battery may be destroyed. Normally zeners are used on batteries to prevent the battery voltage from going too high, not too low - in other words, overcharge protection.